# Pythonic random list of booleans of length n with exactly k Trues

Tags: python, list, random

Say we want a list of `n` `0`/`1` elements with exactly `k` instances of `1`. Is there a one line comprehension or a more pythonic way to do this than the following?

```
def random_include(n, k):
    ret = []
    to_include = set(random.sample([i for i in range(n)], k))
    for i in range(n): 
        if i in to_include:
            ret.append(1)
        ret.append(0)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a one-line solution.

```
output = sorted([1] * k + [0] * (n - k), key=lambda k: random.random())
```

Comment: Personally I find the explicit ``random.shuffle`` much more readable. If you come along a year later and see ``random.shuffle`` it's immediately clear what's going on. Not so with this implementation.

Comment: @ChristianAichinger, I could not agree more, but for the purposes of addressing the OP's request of a one-line solution, this does satisfy his requirement. :)

Comment: Furthermore, [shuffling is hard](http://blog.codinghorror.com/shuffling/). You really want an algorithm like [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to ensure a correct probability distribution! Are you sure the ``sorted()`` approach doesn't fall into that trap?

Comment: @merlin2011 It seems you answered his request for a one-liner "or" a more pythonic way in a pythonic fashion as well by evaluating the first argument to and then not bothering with the other because the first was true. ;)

Comment: @ChristianAichinger, I am most certainly not sure. But I am equally unsure that `random.shuffle()`, from the same Python library, will do much better.

Comment: Take a look at ``random.py`` in your Python directory. It uses exactly the Fisher-Yates algorithm. As it stands, I'd say your implementation probably subtly broken - it generates random-looking sequences but with a non-even probability distribution.

Comment: @ChristianAichinger, I added a note in the answer to address your concern, although I also observe that the OP did not ask for cryptography-level randomness.

Comment: Sorry for being so hard on you, but ``random.py`` is a deterministic RNG, and thus unsuitable for cryptographic work anyway. It's about whether you care if all the sequences should have exactly the same probability or not.

Comment: Playing with your solution a bit seems to give correct results (equal probability though), sorry for making such a fuzz about it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to experiment and update.

Comment: `true randomness`? There is no such thing, I believe :)

Comment: @thefourtheye, Very fair point, I should have been more careful when I use that term. Since Christian has already stated that the results are sufficient to satisfy him, I have removed the note.

Answer (score 5):

Use `random.shuffle` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)):

```
random_list = [False] * j + [True] * k
random.shuffle(random_list)
```

Will give you a random list with `j` times `False` and `k` times `True`.

Note that implementing a custom shuffle algorithm is often problematic, as it's very easy to write an algorithm that produces seemingly-random results, but does not offer a constant probability distribution. I.e. some sequences are more likely than others!

This was extensively explored in [Jeff Atwood's blog post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/shuffling/) on the subject. The correct solution, if you want a properly shuffled sequence is to use the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which is exactly what `random.shuffle()` takes care to do:

```
def shuffle(self, x, random=None, int=int):
    randbelow = self._randbelow
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = randbelow(i+1) if random is None else int(random() * (i+1))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

Thus, it is best to rely on `random.shuffle()` and not come up with a clever way to do shuffling yourself!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback on my solution. This is merely out of curiosity, but why does the fact that `random.shuffle()` is using the `random()` function not cause a problem for Fisher-Yates?
Based on the Wikipedia article on the algorithm, it seems to also have a problem with PRNG.

Comment: Yes, [PRNGs with small states give uneven probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Pseudorandom_generators:_problems_involving_state_space.2C_seeding.2C_and_usage).
The Python random module (``Modules/_randommodule.c``) uses 624 long ints = 19968 bits of internal state. So it would reach its absolute limit shuffling a deck of ~2000 cards (``math.log2(math.factorial(2083))`` is about ``2**19968``). If you are shuffling sequences of fewer than 100-200 elements you should be on the safe side. Great discussion, btw. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
def random_include(n, k):
    my_list = [1] * k + [0] * (n - k)
    random.shuffle(my_list)
    return my_list
```

First construct the list with enough 1s and 0s.

```
my_list = [1] * k + [0] * (n - k)
```

Then shuffle it

```
random.shuffle(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
random.sample([1] * k + [0] * (n - k), n)
```

This returns what you want.